# Solving a Second Order Differential with Matrix input

Tags: matlab, matrix, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second order differential using ODE45 in Matlab with matrix as inputs. I am struck with couple of errors that includes :

```
"In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same."
```

Double order differential equations given below:

```
dy(1)= diag(ones(1,100) - 0.5*y(2))*Co;
dy(2)= -1 * Laplacian(y(1)) * y(2);
```

Main function call is:

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@rigid,[0.000 100.000],[Co Xo]);
```

Here, Co is Matrix of size 100x100 and Xo is a column matrix of size 100x1. Laplacian is a pre-defined function to compute matrix laplacian.

I will appreciate any help in this. Should I reshape input matrices and vectors to fall in same dimensions or something?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. The MATLAB ode suite can solve only vector valued ode, i.e. an ode of the form **y**'=**f**(t,**y**). In your case you should convert `y`, and `dy`, back and forth between a matrix and an array by using `reshape`.

To be more precise, the initial condition will be transformed into the array

```
y0 = reshape([Co Xo], 100*101, 1);
```

while `y` will be obtained with

```
y_matrix = reshape(y, 100, 101);
y1 = y_matrix(:,1:100);
y2 = y_matrix(:,101);
```

After having computed the matrices `dy1` and `dy2` you will have to covert them in an array with

```
dy = reshape([dy1 dy2], 100*101, 1);
```

Aside from the limitations of `ode45` your code gives that error because, in MATLAB, matrices are not indexed in that way. In fact, if you define  `A = magic(5)`, `A(11)` gives the eleventh element of `A` i.e. 1.